# Cannot update a component (`App`) error in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardContext from '../../contexts/DashboardContext';
import authorizeWorker from '../../workers/authorize-worker';

/**
 * A protected route that calls the authorize API and redirects to login
 * on fail
 * @param {Function} component The component to redirect to on success 
 */
const ProtectedRoute  = ({ component }) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
    const dashboardContext = useContext(DashboardContext);
    dashboardContext.setIsDashboard(true);
    const Component = component;

    useEffect(() => {
        authorizeWorker({})
            .then(() => setIsAuthenticated(true))
            .catch(() => setIsAuthenticated(false));
    }, []);

    if (isAuthenticated === true) {
        return <Component />;
    }

    if (isAuthenticated === false) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return null;
}

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.func
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I use this for my router e.g.

`<ProtectedRoute path="/projects" component={Projects} />`

I am recently seeing a warning in the console: `Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`ProtectedRoute`). To locate the bad setState() call inside`ProtectedRoute`, follow the stack trace as described`. Why am I seeing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because **on initial render phase**, you render the component with `setIsDashboard(true);`, usually, you want to do it on mount (`useEffect` with empty dep array).

> There is an **initial render** phase, then [mount phase](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/), see [component's lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

Be sure that `setIsDashboard` is persistent, meaning it is created by React API (like `useState`).

Or its memoized with `useMemo`/`useCallback`, or you will get inifite loop because on every render a new instance of `setIsDashboard` will be created and the dep array (`[setIsDashboard]`) will cause another execution.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component }) => {
  const { setIsDashboard } = useContext(DashboardContext);

  // Make sure `setIsDashboard` persistant
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsDashboard(true);
  }, [setIsDashboard]);

  ...
};
```

Comment: The dependency array assures that the effect will only be used again if the value in the array changes. Because this is a function setState, the function definition will never change and hence the effect will only be called once. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But, **eslint can't know that**, so it will suggest you add it to dep array, and that's OK, that's desired behavior.

Comment: If I am calling an API from useEffect (I just want to call it once on mount) e.g. `authorizeWorker()` is it a good idea to also add that to the dependency array?

Comment: Whatever eslint recommends, it doesn't recommend anything in `authorizeWorker` case, so no.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you can't set state when you are rendering:

`dashboardContext.setIsDashboard(true);` is probably the problem.

You don't post your stack trace or line numbers so it's hard to tell exactly what the issue is:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I didn't realize I was doing it as part of the render. Isn't the render the part of the code in the return blocks? Where is gerneally recommended to set state, useEffect?